# How can I prevent stack backtracing information?

Tags: c, gdb

Imagine you have some code, compile it, and strip it of all symbols. If you run gdb on it, stop it at an arbitrary point, and backtrace it, you will still get meaningful information

```
int baz() {
    sleep(10);
    return 0;
}
int bar() {
    return baz();
}
int foo() {
    return bar();
}
int main() {
    return foo();
}

$ gcc -fomit-frame-pointer test.c 
$ strip -x a.out 
$ gdb ./a.out 


#0  0x0000003a4989a470 in __nanosleep_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003a4989a2c4 in sleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000000004004b7 in baz ()
#3  0x00000000004004cf in bar ()
#4  0x00000000004004e2 in foo ()
#5  0x00000000004004f5 in main ()
```

suppose you want to prevent users to see (or obfuscate) from baz to main. Is it possible? Hardcore methods welcome.

Comment: If you compile without frame pointers, you can strip the unwind sections out of the binary, or remove the assembler directives that generate them from the assembly before assembling.

Comment: What compiler/strip versions are you using?

Comment: You could write your program in *Continuation Passing Style*. That's difficult to do in C, I admit. But since CPS does not use the stack, there's no stack trace.

Comment: Alternative solution: do not ship your code to anyone you think might use a debugger on it. Host the code on your server and provide a web service interface for your customers.

Comment: @Eric: interesting the continuation passing style, but if you implement it in C, wouldn't it require to reset the stack at every continuation? otherwise, at every call of the continuation routine, it will push into it until it overflows.

Comment: @StefanoBorini: correct; in CPS *every* method call is a tail call, so you can simply re-use the sole existing stack frame.

Answer (score 4):

You can not prevent a stack trace if you wish your functions to be able to return.

If returning is not necessary then then overwriting the return address and frame pointer will prevent a stack trace

```
int bar() {
    int nptrs; void * buffer[100];
    nptrs = backtrace(buffer, 100);
    backtrace_symbols_fd(buffer, nptrs, STDOUT_FILENO);

    // this is machine and compiler specific
    // the following works for most i386 compilant compilers that create frame pointers
    void ** stack_base_pointer;
    __asm__ ("mov %%rbp, %0" : "=g" (stack_base_pointer));

    // we will save the original values
    void * return_address = stack_base_pointer[1];
    void * frame_pointer = stack_base_pointer[0];
    // overwrite them
    stack_base_pointer[1] = NULL;
    stack_base_pointer[0] = NULL;
    // this function can not return now

    printf("return_address = %p\nframe pointer = %p\n", return_address, frame_pointer);
    puts("Removed return address and frame pointer");

    nptrs = backtrace(buffer, 100);
    backtrace_symbols_fd(buffer, nptrs, STDOUT_FILENO);

    // we need to restore the return address in order to be able to return
    stack_base_pointer[1] = return_address;

    return 0;
}

int foo() {
    puts("calling bar");
    bar();
    puts("successfully returned from bar");
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

But please note that this will be specific to both the compiler and the target system you are compiling for.

On OS X compiled with `Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)`:

```
$ ./a.out
calling bar
0   a.out                               0x000000010e23cd7f bar + 31
1   a.out                               0x000000010e23ce48 foo + 26
2   a.out                               0x000000010e23ce69 main + 14
3   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff905a35fd start + 1
return_address = 0x10e23ce48
frame pointer = 0x7fff519c3b90
Removed return address and frame pointer
0   a.out                               0x000000010e23cdff bar + 159
successfully returned from bar
```

Answer (score 2):

As already said by M. Waltz in comments.

From strip manual page:

> ```
>    -x
>    --discard-all
>        Remove non-global symbols.
> ```

Resulting backtrace: __nanosleep_nocancel, __sleep, baz, bar, foo, main

```
   -s
   --strip-all
       Remove all symbols.
```

Resulting backtrace: __nanosleep_nocancel, __sleep, ?? (), ?? (), ?? (), ?? ()

You really want to use -s, not -x. -x only removes non-global symbols, which for C (for example), means all non-static functions will still have entries in symbol table and will be visible in backtrace (you can use readelf -a a.out to verify).

If you also want to hide the addresses of backtrace, some of it will be done by using higher level of optimization, as functions get inlined and so on. For "really hardcore" you could take a compiler and mess with ABI just enough, so it's not readable by generic tools, but that's probably way too much work.

Answer (score 1):

> suppose you want to prevent users to see (or obfuscate) from baz to main. Is it possible? Hardcore methods welcome.

On Linux seems it is possible to hide some of your functions. Use shared libraries and move all your function except for main in it. Hide functions you don't want to be seen:

```
>more mylib.c
__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden"))) int baz() {
  sleep(10);
  return 0;
}
__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden"))) int bar() {
  return baz();
}
int foo() {
  return bar();
}
```

Build & strip:

```
gcc -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-inline -fpic -shared mylib.c -o libmylib.so
strip -x libmylib.so
```

And run:

```
>gdb -q a.out
Reading symbols from /home/a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/a.out
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x0000003c412ab900 in __nanosleep_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003c412ab900 in __nanosleep_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003c412ab790 in sleep () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7dfc537 in ?? () from libmylib.so
#3  0x00007ffff7dfc54f in ?? () from libmylib.so
#4  0x00007ffff7dfc562 in foo () from libmylib.so
#5  0x00000000004005ba in main ()
(gdb)
```